# Send to Gmail windows 7

Tags: windows-7, gmail

I want to send a file as attachment. So from windows 7 send to menu, I want to create an option "Send to GMail". Which launch gmail in my default browser and attach the file. Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [install gAttach](http://download.cnet.com/gAttach/3000-2367_4-10861891.html), set it as your default mail client, then use the sent to > mail recipient menu.

It appears the gAttach link in the source page is dead, most likely there is no support for this product anymore, use the link above to download a copy of gAttach.

[Source of Information](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-gmail-your-default-desktop-mail-program-windows/)

[Another method here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/send-file-attachment-gmail-email-client-windows-explorer-context-menu/)

Comment: I have tried gattach on windows 7. When I run this program, it hang until i close forcefully.

Comment: Try running it in compatibility mode for Vista or XP.

Comment: From what I've heard, Affixa (http://www.affixa.com/download/) is the new gAttach. It works the same way -- you can use the "Send To > Mail Recipient" windows explorer menu to create a gmail draft and attach the file(s).